# Can you control intensity of AO baking effect on specific material for object A, while baking AO map for Object B which is influenced by A?

Tags: texture-baking

You have object B on which you bake AO map, object A should influence it, but I would like some surfaces of object A to have less/more impact than others.

I know I can separete surfaces to different object and set that object to be ignored for baking, but that would make them completly be ignored, which is not what I would like to achieve.

Or maybe alternatively is there a way to control how much AO effect can object A have while baking AO map on object B?

Answer (score 1):

If you're prepared to use OSL (and therefore CPU), this is a first shot at variable AO-influence.

It's a hack of [François Gastaldo](http://vadrouillegraphique.blogspot.fr/)'s AO shader, found among [Sambler's collection](https://github.com/sambler/osl-shaders/blob/master/ramps/FGgao_ambient_occlusion/FGgao_ambient_occlusion.osl).

Having declared `matIdx` earlier, it makes the following change, which multiplies the factor of the mix between background color and AO color, according to the Pass Index of the material struck by the AO probe ray.

[image]

In the following illustration, the white box is directly shaded by the script.The red cubes have materials with indices 0,32,64,128, and 200:

[image]

There are a couple of simpler AO scripts in the collection that could serve instead, and you might want to refine the exact effect. But this could be a starting-point.

[image]

Comment: nice! exactly what I was hoping exists, thank you

Comment: I have been experimenting with that and I can get material to behave how I like for render, but how do I use that for baking AO map, no matter what I do baked results is always the same and ignores any custom osl scripts in materials

Comment: Hi, @robert  ! .. fine, at my end. Are you by any chance baking AO? That would be the internal AO, not ours.  [Here](https://imgur.com/a/lcGPpQo), the tree is plugged straight into the Material Output, as in the upload, and the _Emission_ is baked.

Comment: Oh thank you, that makes sense.